# loop list of json strings and change element every N time

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I have a `function` that takes a `list` of `json` strings and replaces `[link]` with one item of a `list` of links, and I want to replace `[link]` with every `N` (variable) item of the `list`.

```
import itertools


ll = [
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
        ]
    },
]

links = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']


def changer(ll):
    cy = itertools.cycle(links)
    for i in ll:
        ni = i.replace('[link]', next(cy))
        print(next(cy))
        print(type(ni))
```

For example, if `N = 2` for every 2 items of the `list` cycle to the `next` link.

But my code replaces all with the first element of the `list` **'aaa'** in this case.

The result should look like this:

```
N = 2

[
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'},
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: When you `print(next(cy))`, the iterable moves to the next element, you can't go back. You're essentially doing `next` twice when you only want to do it once per iteration.

Comment: Also, how are you calling the function `changer`?

Comment: when i `print(next(cy))` output is "bbb" which is the second element of the list links and `ni = i.replace('[link]', next(cy)) ` keep replacing all with "aaa"

and I want `next(cy)` to cycle the next element in links for each element in ll

Comment: maybe you should use `enumerate()` - `for number, item in enumerat(ll): if number % N == 0: next(cy)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop with `zip`:

```
for d1, l in zip(ll, links):
    for d2 in d1['Messages']:
        d2['Text'] = d2['Text'].replace('[link]', l)
```

modified `ll`:

```
[{'Messages': [{'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'},
               {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'}]},
 {'Messages': [{'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'},
               {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'}]},
 {'Messages': [{'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with ccc !'},
               {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with ccc !'}]},
]
```

Comment: but list ll and links have different lengths, i want to cycle thru links

Comment: if links list is shorter than ll, the rest of ll element will remain [link]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate()` to assign `number` to every item on list and run `next(cy)` only when `number % N == 0`

---

Working example.

I used more readable names for variables.

```
import itertools

data = [
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'Messages': [
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
            {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with [link] !'},
        ]
    },
]

links = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

N = 2

links_cycle = itertools.cycle(links)

for number, item in enumerate(data):
    
    if number % N == 0:
        new_link = next(links_cycle)
        
    for message in item['Messages']:
        message['Text'] = message['Text'].replace('[link]', new_link)
        
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
{'Messages': [{'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'}, 
              {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'}]}

{'Messages': [{'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'}, 
              {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with aaa !'}]}

{'Messages': [{'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'}, 
              {'id': 'int', 'Text': 'string with bbb !'}]}
```

---

**BTW:**

Other method: create list with repeated values

```
links = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

which you can create using

```
links = [item for item in links for _ in range(N)]
```

and next run `next()` in every loop.

It can be useful when you would repeat some values different times

ie. `aaa` x 1 , `bbb` x 3 , `ccc` x 2

```
links = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

which you caan create using

```
N = [1, 3, 2]
links = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

links = [item for item, number in zip(links, N) for _ in range(number)]
```